# Не работает форматирование кода на C# в Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, форматирование-кода

Не могу найти решение для форматирования кода на С# с помощью команды <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>. Команда работает для файлов js, а для cs нет. Пробовал вносить изменения в json-файлы, скачивал расширения, устанавливал глобально prettier-plugin-csharp, всё равно. Я только осваиваю программирование, поэтому можете показать подробно как корректировать строки?

Answer (score 1):

Спустя сотню различных попыток получилось следующим образом:

1. Добавление строк ниже в JSON

```
    "[csharp]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
    },
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "never",
    "csharp.suppressProjectJsonWarning": true
```

2. Добавление галочки в csharp.suppressProjectJsonWarning (Settings > C# Configuration > Csharp: Suppress Project JSON Warning), или последняя строка в JSON.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте снять галочку, перезапустить vscode. Затем вернуть обратно. У меня получилось вернуть на место со второго перезапуска vs code

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло